# NSClassFromString(MyClassName) than calling class function of MyClass

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, static-functions

i got a UIViewCustom Class with 7 childs.
each of the childs got their own class functions for helping initiating

```
+(int) minHeight;
+(int) minWidth;
```

in a UITableView i select one of the classes and the function "-insertNewObjectWithClassName:(NSString*)childClassName" gets called.

In that function i want to create the instance depending to the classname, so i tryed

```
Class *class = NSClassFromString(childClassName);
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [class minWidth], [class minWidth])
MotherClass *view = [[class alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

But unfortunately the static function can't be called.

Is there a way, to say the compiler that class is not just a Class but also a MotherClass to tell him the function?

thank you very much!

EDIT: 
Warning: Semantic Issue: Method '-minWidth' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

SOLUTION: Class class instead of Class *class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer seems related: [How do I call +class methods in Objective C without referencing the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931937/how-do-i-call-class-methods-in-objective-c-without-referencing-the-class)

You can define an interface that has the methods you want to call and then have something like:

```
Class<MyCoolView> class = NSClassFromString(childClassName);
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [class getMinWidth], [class getMinWidth]);
MotherClass *view = [[class alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

This should eliminate compiler warnings and make your code typesafe.

Comment: THANK You you are my HERO! The warning has left

Comment: That'll work, but a protocol is overkill.  I'd go with an abstract base class and simply declare `class` to be `MyAbstractBase* class`.  This is cleaner and more indicative of intention;  protocols are for functionality spread across the class hierarchy.  In this case, all of you custom classes are rooted with a single base subclass of `UIView` (I'm guessing UIView).

Comment: I agree that it seems like overkill, but I don't know of a better way in this case.  I don't think code like `MyAbstractBase * class = NSClassFromString(@"someClassName")` will work since the return type is Class and MyAbstractBase* should point at an instance of a MyAbstractBase* and not the class type.

Answer (score 3):

Something must be wrong elsewhere, e.g. the name of the class you are passing. This demo program works as expected (layout compacted for brevity):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyChild
+ (int) minHeight;
+ (int) minWidth;
@end

@implementation MyChild
+ (int) minHeight { return 100; }
+ (int) minWidth { return 300; }
@end

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *className = [NSString stringWithString: @"MyChild"];
    Class theClass = NSClassFromString(className);
    NSLog(@"%d %d", [theClass minHeight], [theClass minWidth]);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2011-08-10 18:15:13.877 ClassMethods[5953:707] 100 300
```

Comment: Hi, i used Class * theClass = NSClassFromString(className);
So the Pointer was the Problem

Answer (score 2):

- Objective-C does not have static functions.  It has Methods;  class or instance.
- do not prefix methods with `get`;  that is reserved for a particular use case, this isn't it.

Your code looks more or less correct.  Are you sure that `childClassName` contains the correct name of the class?

In general, your question indicates a bit of a lack of an understanding of Objective-C or, at the least, an assumption that Obj-C works like C++ (or Java).  I would suggest perusing the [language documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) as it will answer various meta questions that will make all of this pretty clear.

Comment: @Seega: not class **functions**. They are **methods**. The way they are invoked is not the same as how functions are called.